# Definition of Local L-function for a representation of a torus?

Tags: l-functions, langlands-conjectures

Let $G$ be a connected, reductive group over a $p$-adic field $k$.  Let $\pi$ be an irreducible, admissible representation of $G(k)$, and $r$ a finite dimensional continuous representation of the $L$-group $^LG$ of $G$ whose restriction to $^LG^0$ is analytic.  Conjecturally, there should be a local L-function $L(s,\pi,r)$ and $\epsilon$-factor $\epsilon(s,\pi,r,\psi)$ attached to $\pi$ and $r$ (for a chosen additive character $\psi$ of $k$), but so far there are no general definitions.  They are defined for example if $G$ and $\pi$ are unramified.

What about when $G= T$ is a torus?  Are there definitions for $L(s,\pi,r)$ and $\epsilon(s,\pi,r,\psi)$, for $\pi$ a continuous homomorphism $T(k) \rightarrow \mathbb C^{\ast}$?

Comment: I believe this paper might be relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05367.pdf